# How do I connect 2 m3u playlists together?

Tags: m3u8, kodi, m3u, iptv

is it possible for me to create a m3u playlist that plays videos which are in 2 other m3u playlists?

Let me try to explain...

Suppose I create a file called playlist1.m3u and playlist2.m3u

---

(Contents of playlist1.m3u)

## EXTM3U

## EXTINF:-1,MP4 Home Video S1E01

(Mp4 Link Goes Here)

## EXTINF:-1,MP4 Home Video S1E02

(MP4 Link Goes Here)

## EXTINF:-1,MP4 Home Video S1E103

(MP4 Link Goes Here)

### #EXTINF:-1,MP4 Home Video S1E104

Contents of playlist2.m3u)

## EXTM3U

## EXTINF:-1,MP4 Home Video S2E3

(MP4 LINK)

## EXTINF:-1,MP4 Home Video S1E2

(MP4 Link)

## EXTINF:-1,MP4 Home Video S1E3

(MP4 Link)

## EXTINF:-1,MP4 Home Video S1E4

(MP4 Link)

---

So is it possible to connect Season 1 m3u Playlist and Season 2 m3u Playlist (Of Home Videos) together to be played in a 3rd m3u file?

Basically I'm wondering if I can create a m3u file which plays videos listed in 2 other m3u files.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create a nested playlist like this, but getting a player to properly play it back seems to be a bit of an issue.

VLC used to support this, but I've seen recent reports that there are issues with it.

I'm not sure if or how this is actually specified anywhere so the answer does seem to be dependent on the player - hence if you want a solution that will play with different players this may be an issues for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use.

```
#EXTINF:-1 group-title="SERVER 8" logo="icon.png", Playlist title
playlist1.m3u8
playlist2.m3u8
```

Works well with the current version of VLC